# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, theano

I am trying to make a `custom layer`. My layer code is,

```
from keras import backend as K
from theano import tensor as T
from theano.tensor.signal.conv import conv2d
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import regularizers
from keras import constraints
from keras import activations
from keras import initializers
import functools
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import pdb



def OD_init(input_shape, ref_img_path):
    '''This function initialized the SDLayer with Stain-Matrix obtained via SVD.'''
    squeeze_percentile = 99.9
    query = imread(ref_img_path) / 255.0
    phi,a = GetWedgeMacenko(query, squeeze_percentile)
    init = phi
    return [K.reshape(init,input_shape)]

class SDLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, phi=None, init='glorot_uniform',
                dim_ordering='th', activation=None, border_mode='same', 
                W_constraint=None, W_regularizer=None, **kwargs):
        self.dim_ordering = dim_ordering
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.initial_weights = phi
        self.init = initializers.get(init)
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.border_mode = border_mode

        super(SDLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self,input_shape):

        self.W_shape = (3,3,1,1)  # 3 filters of size 3x1x1. The weights are actually inv(S.V.)

        self.W = self.add_weight(shape = self.W_shape,
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint,
                                 initializer=functools.partial(self.init), #,dim_ordering='th'
                                 trainable=True)
        
        if self.initial_weights is not None:
            self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
            #del self.initial_weights

        super(SDLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self,I,mask=None):
        
        PHI     = self.W
        PHI_INV = T.nlinalg.matrix_inverse(K.reshape(self.W,(3,3)))
        PHI_INV = K.reshape(PHI_INV,(3,3,1,1))

        mask  = (1.0 - (I > 0.)) * 255.0
        I = I + mask  # this image contains 255 wherever it had 0 initially

        I_OD = - T.log10(I/255.0)


        A = K.conv2d(I_OD,PHI_INV, border_mode='same')
        A = self.activation(A)    

        return A
    
    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):

        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[1],input_shape[2],input_shape[3])


'''
This file contains my implementation of the method to determine 
Stain Vector using SVD as outlined in the following paper:-

Macenko, Marc, et al. "A method for normalizing histology slides for quantitative analysis." 
Biomedical Imaging: From Nano to Macro, 2009.
ISBI'09. IEEE International Symposium on. IEEE, 2009.
'''

import numpy as np
import math 
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

def rgb2od(img):
    img[np.where(img == 0)] = np.min(img[np.where(img > 0)])
    return -K.log(img)

def od2rgb(img):
    return K.exp(-img)

def rodrigues_rot_matrix(v,k,theta):
    '''
        This function implements rotation of vectors in v,
        along the directions specified in k, by an angle theta
        
        v,k are arrays like [[1,2,3]]
        theta is an array like [[1,2,3,....]]
    '''
        
    v = v.astype('float32')
    k = k.astype('float32')
    theta = theta.astype('float32')    
            
    k = k / math.sqrt(k[0,0]*k[0,0] + k[0,1]*k[0,1] + k[0,2]*k[0,2]) #normalize the normal vector
    
    crosskv = np.zeros(v[0,:].shape) # initialize cross of k and v with the correct dimension 
    crosskv[0] = k[0,1]*v[0,2] - k[0,2]*v[0,1]
    crosskv[1] = k[0,2]*v[0,0] - k[0,0]*v[0,2]
    crosskv[2] = k[0,0]*v[0,1] - k[0,1]*v[0,0] 
    theta_t = np.transpose(theta)
    
    return K.transpose(np.cos(theta_t)*np.transpose(v[0,:])+ \
                        np.sin(theta_t)*np.transpose(crosskv) + \
                        np.dot((1-np.cos(theta_t)),k*np.dot(k,v[0,:])))

def GetOrthogonalBasis(image_rgb):
    w,h,d =  image_rgb.shape
    
    img_od = np.transpose(np.reshape(rgb2od(image_rgb),[w*h,3]))
        
    # remove pixels below threshold
    img_od_norm = np.sqrt(np.sum(img_od**2,0))
    good = img_od_norm > 0.15
    img_od_good = img_od[:,good]
        
    phi_ortho = scipy.linalg.svd(img_od_good,full_matrices=False)[0]
    # reverse any axis having more than one negative value
    mask = phi_ortho<0
    cols = np.where(np.sum(mask,0)>1,1,0)
    phi_ortho = np.transpose([-phi_ortho[:,j] if cols[j] else phi_ortho[:,j] for j in range(len(cols))])
    a_ortho = np.dot(scipy.linalg.pinv(phi_ortho),img_od)
    
    return phi_ortho, a_ortho

def GetWedgeMacenko(image_rgb, squeeze_percentile):
    phi_ortho, a_ortho = GetOrthogonalBasis(image_rgb)
    
    image_od = np.dot(phi_ortho,a_ortho)
    phi_wedge = phi_ortho
    phi_plane = phi_ortho[:,[0,1]]
    a_plane = a_ortho[[0,1],:]    
    
    # normalize a_plane
    a_plane_normalized = normalize(a_plane,axis=0,norm='l2')
     
    #find robust extreme angles
    min_a = np.percentile(np.arctan(a_plane_normalized[1,:]/a_plane_normalized[0,:]),squeeze_percentile)
    max_a = np.percentile(np.arctan(a_plane_normalized[1,:]/a_plane_normalized[0,:]),100-squeeze_percentile)
    
    
    phi_1 = rodrigues_rot_matrix(np.array([phi_plane[:,0]]), \
                                 np.array([np.cross(phi_plane[:,0],phi_plane[:,1])]),np.array([min_a]))
    phi_2 = rodrigues_rot_matrix(np.array([phi_plane[:,0]]), \
                                 np.array([np.cross(phi_plane[:,0],phi_plane[:,1])]),np.array([max_a]))
    
    phi_wedge[:,[0,1]] = np.transpose([phi_1,phi_2])
    a_wedge = np.dot(scipy.linalg.pinv(phi_ortho), image_od)
    
    return K.variable(phi_wedge),K.variable(a_wedge)
```

I am trying to make a `custom layer` and its getting error. When I `feed layer` to `input layer`

```
inputs = Input(shape=(3,500,500))
x = Conv2D(6, 3)(inputs)
OD_img = SDLayer(activation='tanh', phi=OD_init((3,3,1,1), ref_img_path) ) (x)
```

Error shows:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (sd_layer_1/Reshape:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported**
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downgrading the NumPy version. My TensorFlow version is 1.15.2 and I downgraded NumPy to 1.16.